# Operator ++= on a pair in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have written the following in Scala:

```
implicit class Appender[A, B](x: (Growable[A], Growable[B])) {
  def ++=(y: (TraversableOnce[A], TraversableOnce[B])): (Growable[A], Growable[B]) =
    (x._1 ++= y._1, x._2 ++= y._2)
}
```

But Scala doesn't accept `x._2 ++= y._2`, complaining that: `Expression of type Growable.this.type doesn't conform to expected type Growable[B]`.

I also tried:

[image]

for which IntelliJ suggests a return type of `(Growable.this.type, Growable.this.type)`, which leads to other problems.

What am I missing? What would be the correct way to add this `++=` operation to a `Tuple2` of 2 `Growable`?

Is there a way to write that kind of "lifting" but generalizing it to the operation (here `++=`) too? That would be some implicit `Lift` that can transfer an operation from the type inside a pair to the pair type itself. Is that possible in Scala?

Comment: Try compiling with Scala compiler. It's just the type checker in the IDE sometimes doesn't understand perfectly normal Scala code.

Comment: It seems genuine (ie not just in IntelliJ) - the compiler refuses if I try to return `(AA, AA)` in the example with `A` and `AA`.

Comment: Your first snippet with `x: (Growable[A], Growable[B])` compiles and works fine for me.

Comment: Not for me, because I have a specific subtype of `Growable[A]` (actually I have `A` = `B`), and the returned type `(Growable.this.type, Growable.this.type)` is not automatically casted to my specific subtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first snippet compiles and works fine for me, although IntelliJ underlines it.

The problem with this code though is that it loses information about the concrete types in the first pair. The result comes out as the opaque `(Growable[A], Growable[B])`.

To preserve the types you can use something similar to the second snippet. The problem is that the compiler seems unable to apply the implicit conversion to the pair of `Growable` subtypes. But if you try to create the `Appender` explicitly it works:

```
object Test {
  implicit class Appender[
    A, GA <: Growable[A],
    B, GB <: Growable[B]
  ](x: (GA, GB)) {
    def ++=(y: (TraversableOnce[A], TraversableOnce[B])): (GA, GB) = {
      (x._1 ++= y._1, x._2 ++= y._2)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = (ArrayBuffer(1,2,3), ArrayBuffer("a","b","c"))
    println(new Appender(a).++=((List(4,5,6), List("d","e","f"))))
  }
}
```

You can assist the compiler by defining the parts of `x` with a combined type `GA with Growable[A]`. In that case the compiler detects and applies the implicit conversion correctly using the `Growable[A]` part of the declaration. And you still have access to the full type `GA` to return from the method:

```
object Test {
  implicit class Appender[
    A, GA <: Growable[A],
    B, GB <: Growable[B]
  ](x: (GA with Growable[A], GB with Growable[B])) {
    def ++=(y: (TraversableOnce[A], TraversableOnce[B])): (GA, GB) = {
      (x._1 ++= y._1, x._2 ++= y._2)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = (ArrayBuffer(1,2,3), ArrayBuffer("a","b","c"))
    println(a ++= (List(4,5,6), List("d","e","f")))
  }
}
```

**Append:**

As for your bonus question, I don't think there is a simple way to automate the creation of all methods. Maybe you can do something with macros, but I'm not sure. But I believe you can considerably simplify method definitions using some helper methods. There are not that many methods you can meaningfully define for `Growable`, so here is what I believe a full definition:

```
implicit class Appender[
  A, GA <: Growable[A]
](x: (GA with Growable[A], GA with Growable[A])) {
  private def wrap[B, R](f: GA => B => R): ((B, B)) => (R, R) =
    y => (f(x._1)(y._1), f(x._2)(y._2))

  val ++= = wrap(_.++=)
  val += = wrap(_.+=)

  def clear(): Unit = {
    x._1.clear()
    x._2.clear()
  }
}
```

If you have some other operation

```
def myOpDef[A, GA <: Growable[A]](ga: GA, traversable: TraversableOnce[A]): GA = ???
```

you can also add it to the `Appender` definition (but it seems a bit tricky):

```
val myOp = wrap(ga => myOpDef(ga, _))
```

or

```
val myOp = wrap(myOpDef[A, GA].curried)
```

Comment: Thanks! Bonus question: is it possible to generalize by abstracting out `++=`, so that we can automatically pass any (operation that takes a `Growable` and a `Traversable` to a `Growable`) to (an operation that takes a pair of `Growable`, a pair of `Traversable` and returns a pair of `Growable`)? I'm lazy and don't want to write a `def xyz` for every function `xyz` of `Growable` :-)

Comment: I confirmed that your second solution works for me too. It is my choice: it seems a bit more elegant than the first one, although we shouldn't have to "assist the compiler", IMHO.

Comment: @Frank See if my edit answers your question. Also, I agree that we shouldn't have to assist the compiler, but I have an impression that those kinds of things are really non-trivial and may be approaching the limit of what is feasible to do with Scala's type system, which has to support OOP with subclasses, but also FP and all kinds of implicit resolution. I maybe wrong with that opinion though, and it's just an oversight.

Comment: thanks. The wrappers are not working in my context yet, but I'll continue working on it. I algo got in trouble when I defined an `Appender1` with `A`  only and `Appender2` with types `A` and `B`, both with a pair on the LHS but with a single collection on the RHS for `Appender1` for `++=`, with the semantic that `++=` adds the same things to both elements of the pair for `Appender1`. It seemed to get confused about `++=` in that case.